# Why radio button binding in view model gets fired more than one time

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have my xaml for my windows phone here which has radio button, but sometimes its really confusing.

I am not binding in code behind all done is xaml.

any pointer would be helpful.

here's the code,

```
<RadioButton Name="rdbChoice1"
Padding="5,0,5,0"
Content="x"
IsChecked="{Binding IsChoice1,Mode=TwoWay}"></RadioButton>
<RadioButtonName="rdbChoice2"
Padding="5,0,5,0"
Content="Not x"
IsChecked="{Binding IsChoice1,Converter={StaticResourceInverseBooleanConverter},Mode=OneWay}"></RadioButton>>
```

Comment: show us code .. how do u expect help by only 3 sentences ...

Comment: Can we see the XAML please ?

Comment: You've bound to the same property twice - why wouldn't it fire twice? Two controls are binding to the same prop on the VM. Is there any issue that it's firing twice?

Comment: you have to set group name.I hope that would fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the group name and that would fix the issue